# Styling User Controlled Defined Closeable TabItem

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, tabcontrol, controltemplate, tabitem

I have designed a `tab item` with close button with the help of user control. Now I am having problem styling that UC. My `Style Resource` works perfectly on default `tabitems`

**Closeable Tab Item User Control**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 < Style TargetType="TabItem" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border Background="{x:Null}">
                <TextBlock Background="Aquamarine">
                    <ContentPresenter
                                                                ContentSource="Header"

                        ></ContentPresenter>
                </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid >
    <Button Background="Red">x</Button>        
    <TextBlock>Custom Tab Item</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

P.S

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem) , The problem is simple, I want to change background color of TabItem that I created with the help of user control. But the style resource I have written only changes background color of default wpf tab items.

Comment: You will need to provide more information on this. Maybe show a code snippet of your usage. And explain the problem further.

Comment: I am following this tutorial, The problem is simple, I want to change background color of TabItem that I created with the help of custom control. But the style resource I have written only changes background color of default wpf tab item
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem

Answer (score 1):

Thats a simplyfied version of how I solved a similar problem before. I setted the TabControls ItemTemplate to what I wanted

```
             <TabControl>
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="closeBtn" Content="X" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="15" Margin="15 0 0 0" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HeaderText}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=LoadedFile}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
             </TabControl>
```

Comment: I don't know how to use that? can you show me some more sample of it?